# Avoiding the Promise constructor anti-pattern: how do I reject?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Instead of writing my functions like this:

```
const clearContent = (animation = Promise.resolve()) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const child = $('#child');

    animation.then(animationEvent => {
        const eventPackage = {
            'divRemoved': 'divIDPlaceholder',
            'itemRemoved': 'contentIDPlaceholder',
            'remainingItemsCount': 2,
            'remainingItems': 1
        };

        child.remove();

        const contentRemovedEvent = new CustomEvent('contentRemovedFromPlaceholder', {
            'detail': eventPackage
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(contentRemovedEvent);

        console.log('Removed!');

        return resolve(eventPackage);
        });
});
}
```

I think I now get how to write them without introducing unneeded complexity. I avoid creating a new `Promise` since they are inherently thenable:

```
const clearContent = (animation = Promise.resolve()) => {

    const child = $('#child');

    return animation.then(animationEvent => {
        const eventPackage = {
            'divRemoved': 'divIDPlaceholder',
            'itemRemoved': 'contentIDPlaceholder',
            'remainingItemsCount': 2,
            'remainingItems': 1
        };

        child.remove();

        const contentRemovedEvent = new CustomEvent('contentRemovedFromPlaceholder', {
            'detail': eventPackage
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(contentRemovedEvent);

        console.log('Removed!');

        return eventPackage;
    });
}
```

Whatever happens inside the `animation.then(()...` affects the promise of `animation`. It will not resolve until whatever's inside here doens't also "resolve" and there's my problem.

If `return` is the signal that everything is alright, what is the counter? How do I tell `animation` to not resolve?

Comment: By "not to resolve", do you mean "to reject instead"? You do that by `throw`ing an exception, or returning another promise that is rejected.

Comment: You can `throw new Error(...)` and then `.catch()` it on the promise.

Comment: Correct. "to reject instead". As such, just to confirm, functions than then depend on `clearContent`'s either `resolve/reject` will now hit the `reject` of it if `throw` is used?

Comment: Yes -----------

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Comment: Awesome. Just tested. Will read and I hope I can figure out how to apply things properly.